# Can a javascript dropdown in-email like G+ be implemented by anyone, or only Google?

Tags: javascript, email, gmail, google-plus, html-email

Noticed today this great trinket from Google: in their notification emails upon new G+ followers, the recipient can add someone to a circle directly from a dropdown in the email.  (See below).

The HTML for the page clearly shows the related `div` has been attached to the end of the body, suggesting that the div di not 'ship with' the email and then was displayed via in-email javascript.

Is this kind of interactivity available to any engineer / product developer?  Is this only something that Google gets to do because they control Gmail services?

---

[image]

Comment: You can put drop-down lists in any web site you create, just like Google has done.

Comment: @Pointy, I think he means can he hook up a javascript event in a email like Google has done.

Comment: Why do you think that since the element is at the end of the `<body>`, that it's not part of the library/page naturally? Many libraries use this method for adding elements, for several reasons

Comment: @Brandon But there isn't any Javascript in the email. When Google displays the email on the page, they put the dropdown functionality there.

Comment: @Brandon ah.  Well GMail/Google+ are Google websites. Google wrote the code to present email on the web via an HTML interface. Anybody else is free to create an email service with an HTML interface. You cannot, however, predict whether people reading email you send them will do so via any particular user interface mechanism.

Comment: @Brandon is onto my point here.  GOogle may have setup Gmail to look for G+ emails, find a given element, and attach a listener..... but this functionality would not be available to all developers.  Or did they do this another way, which is available to all developers?

Answer (score 4):

The Google+ integration you see is specific to Gmail:

http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/better-google-notification-experience.html

In general you will not be able to run javascript in gmail or other webmail providers due to security concerns.  There are ways of making more interactive emails, however they are generally platform specific.  For example:

- Gmail offers [Contextual Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/contextual_gadgets#what_is_a_gmail_contextual_gadget) (used by Xobni and other inbox apps)
- Outlook/Hotmail offers [Active Views](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_live/b/windowslive/archive/2010/12/16/hotmail-introduces-interactive-email-using-active-views.aspx)